# Does Far Cry 4 need any bandwidth?

Tags: far-cry-4

I'm looking to get Far Cry 4 for my computer. I do believe the game is thirty gigabytes, and my internet is capped. If I were to get the game on a disk, would it still use bandwidth, or would it install directly to my hard drive?

Comment: Which game?  It's going to depend greatly on the game, and what version you get.

Comment: Depends on the game, which for some bizarre reason you elected not to mention. Some games include most or all of the necessary data on the disk. With others, the disk is just a download code.

Comment: Without a game, we can't reasonably answer your question. Asking us to detail this functionality for every single game in existence is a little much. I've edited your question to be specifically about Far Cry 4 as that's the one you're asking about.

Comment: @Jake Yes, the game matters enormously. Some games package very little on the disc and require a download for the rest; for some games the whole thing is on the disc and you only need to download patches (and those aren't necessary).

Comment: @Jake You are *not* getting hate on this site. I don't understand why people like to throw this word around so much. Hate is a very strong emotion and I highly doubt that's something experienced by anyone while commenting on this question. People were simply puzzled why you didn't include the name of the game. That is all.

Comment: If you consider asking follow up questions to be hate, the real world is going to be a nasty shock for you.

Comment: No of course not. But I feel 6 down votes in total, in less than 12 hours is a lot lol. Not the questions I have been receiving; I welcome them with open arms.

Comment: I bought FC4 on the weekend, I don't have great internet access so I got the DVD version (3 disks!!!). After I installed it I had 3Gb worth of patches to download.

Answer (score 1):

Though the majority of the game will be installed, forum posts such as [this](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1471486-I-can-not-install-Far-Cry-4-from-DVD?p=11841388&viewfull=1#post11841388) (from 2016) suggest that:

> the version that comes on the DVD's is outdated by almost 2 years

and that

> and many of those 8 patches were several gig in size anyway

This post is, in itself, probabably outdated by now.

Answer (score 0):

Once installed, Far Cry 4 can be played in offline mode, which uses very little, if any, bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/452910-installing-skyrim-from-the-dvd/

This post details how to force Steam to install a game from the disk instead of download. There will most likely be an update or 2 after install, but it probably won't even reach a half gig.

Comment: I don't think this would apply with Far Cry 4 since it's a UPlay game, not a Steam game. The DVD version wouldn't come with a Steam key.